# Named class instance

Tags: haskell

Is there way of simplifying function type headers that contains classes?

Now I write

```
myfce :: Graph gr => Sometype -> gr Int String
```

and I would want

```
myfce :: Sometype -> MyGraph
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyGraph` is a type synonym for `x Int String` where `x` is an instance of `Graph`, then you can do this:

```
data GraphType a b = ...

instance Graph GraphType where ...

type MyGraph = GraphType Int String
```

You can then specialize `myfce` to have the type you want

```
myfce :: Sometype -> MyGraph
```